# Create a Backbone.Model to manage a server connection

Tags: backbone.js

So basically, I want building a test app where I need to enter server credentials in order to connect to an ElasticSearch server and I want this connection to be only available for the duration of the session.

I thought this could be managed via Backbone.Model but I'm not too sure how to handle it. Do I need a Collection as well. Do I store this in the Session or locaStorage?

#### Page 1

Form with protocol, host, post, username, password

```
Backbone.View.extend
...
events: {
 'submit #connection-form' : 'connect'
},
...
connect: function(){
      console.log('Connecting...');
      protocol = $("#protocol").val();
      host = $("#host").val();
      port = $("#port").val();
      user = $("#username").val();
      password = $("#password").val();
      App.connection = new Connection({ protocol: protocol, host: host, port: port, user: user, password: password})

      self = this
      App.connection.connect(function(response){
        if (response.status == 200) {
          App.connection.set('name', response.name)
          App.router.navigate('dashboard', {trigger: true});
        } else {
          $(self.el).prepend(_.template(noticeTpl, { type: 'danger', message: "Could not connect to the server." }))
        }
      });

      return false;
    }
```

#### Page 2

List of indexes on my ElasticSearch server

I need to store what have been submitted on page one across all the session in order to be able to query the server at any time.

Answer (score 0):

No reason you'll need a collection since you're only dealing with a single object. I also don't see any reason to use localStorage unless you're storing a lot of data, which you aren't, or want the app to be usable offline, which doesn't make any sense here.

Using sessionStorage is pretty straightforward:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Comment: At the moment, on page refresh, all the connection data are lost. How can I manage this ?